# Informix weekday calendar function not working

Tags: calendar, time-series, informix

I am new to Informix. I tried creating timeseries calendar pattern which should store data only for weekdays (Monday-Friday).

I inserted the data below for that into CalendarPatterns table:

```
INSERT INTO CalendarPatterns (cp_name, cp_pattern)
    VALUES ('5day_ptrn', '{1 off, 5 on, 1 off}, day');
```

While trying to inserting record into a table which is using this calendar pattern, it's storing data for Saturday and Sunday but not storing data for Thursday and Friday.

Please advise where I am going wrong.

Comment: Not territory I'm familiar with.  I found [CalendarPattern data type](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.tms.doc/ids_tms_058.htm) in the manual, and close by there is the [CalendarPatterns table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.tms.doc/ids_tms_066.htm).

Comment: In the first link, there's an example isomorphic with yours: _Calendars that have the same calendar pattern length but different interval sizes are not equivalent. For example, a calendar can be built around a normal five-day work week, with the time unit in days, and Saturday and Sunday as days off. Assuming that the calendar pattern start date is for a Sunday, the syntax for this calendar pattern is:

`INSERT INTO CalendarPatterns
  VALUES('workweek_day',
        '{1 off, 5 on, 1 off}, day');`_

Comment: What I'm guessing is that the 'assuming that the calendar pattern start date is for a Sunday' comment is not correct for your data; it is perhaps starting on Friday.  What I've not worked out is how you fix the start date.  You might need to change the pattern to `'{1 on, 2 off, 4 on}, day'` to get the required result, but more likely there's a way to specify the start date rather than default to today's day of the week.

Comment: The [Calendar data type](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.tms.doc/ids_tms_059.htm) may have some of the relevant information; it mentions 'calendar pattern start date'.